# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2 n}{n^{13} +n^7 + n }$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2 n}{n^{13} +n^7 + n }$ is convergent.

**Attempt:**
Firstly, we know that $-1 \le \cos n \le 1 \Leftrightarrow 0 \le \cos^2 n \le 1$ for all positive integers $n$. On the other hand, it's clear that $n^{13} + n^7 + n \gt n^{13}$ i.e.
$\frac{1}{n^{13}+n^7+n} \lt \frac{1}{n^{13}}$
for all integers $n$. Hence, we have
\begin{equation*}
\cos^2 n \le 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\cos^2 n}{n^{13} + n^7 + n} \le \frac{1}{n^{13} + n^7 + n}
\lt \frac{1}{n^{13}}.
\end{equation*}
We know that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{13}}$ is a convergent $p-$series with $p=13>1$. Therefore, by the Comparison Test,
we have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2 n}{n^{13} + n^7 + n}$ is convergent.

Am I true?

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: @Imago Really? Nice to hear it. Thanks sir.

Comment: Absolutely fine work.

Comment: Perfect, just precise for an examinator that you're comparison works because of everything is positive.